# Not Returning to App After Following Link

Tags: android, android-activity, hyperlink

Content is delivered to my app from a server, sometimes the content contains tel: or mailto: hyperlinks. Currently I use html.fromhtml() and setMovementMethod to make the textview links clickable:

```
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_data)).setText(Html.fromHtml(HTML_out));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_data)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and this works, allows the user to open mailto links, phone links and anything else.

The problem is it closes my app when they click the link, so if they click back from the phone or email it takes them back to the home screen instead of my app.

From what I can see, when the link is clicked for some reason onStop is called. How can I avoid this so the app will be re-opened right after the call/email?

example data:

```
<b>Title1</b><a href="tel:44#######">(44#) ###-####</a>
<b>Title2</b><a href="mailto:test@gmail.com">test@gmail.com</a>
<b>Title3</b><a href="google.ca">google.ca</a>
```

edit: 
I tried to use an intent:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.cust_data)).setText(Html.fromHtml(HTML_out));
//((TextView) findViewById(R.id.cust_data)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.cust_data)).setMovementMethod(new MovementMethod() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(TextView widget, Spannable text) {
        //Log.i("Test click","Good");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(TextView widget, Spannable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(TextView widget, Spannable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //Log.i("Test click","Good");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyOther(TextView view, Spannable text, KeyEvent event) {
        //Log.i("Test click","Good");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTakeFocus(TextView widget, Spannable text, int direction) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(TextView widget, Spannable text, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable text, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.i("Test click", text.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(TextView widget, Spannable text, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSelectArbitrarily() {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Just to text I used a static phone number. This still doesn't take me back to my app after.

Comment: You should probably change this to be an intent to open the link, and if that doesn't work then maybe startActivityForResult() would do it, since it would expect to receive something.

Comment: I would be using static on click intents to open email or the phone, but every users data will be different. So I can't just make a static view with just the link. Am I missing something?

Comment: Follow the first part of Cody's advice. That should work. There is no need to make a "static view", whatever that is.

Comment: @theshadow124 can you give more of your code? I don't understand what you mean by "static view" either. If your concern is that the text can change that wouldn't matter.

Comment: When i say static view... i should have said dedicated. I have one view that I then load with HTML data that is set by my user. There could be many links. How would I setup an intent on a textview to open many different kinds of links?

Comment: Ah, that gets it more complicated. Hang on, I have a project where I've done this before.

Answer (score 1):

From your last comment it sounds like you are going to possibly have several links inside of one textview. If that's the case then what you want is to set the text with a `spannable`, which allows you to determine what links are in there, what their text says, and other formatting like bold or italic text for only part of the text. Try something like this:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder content = getContent(); // This method is explained below.

final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
textView.setLinksClickable(true);
textView.setText(content, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

`getContent()` - This is where it will be more difficult to give you an answer, since we don't know how you're getting your links. When I wrote an application that did this it was pulling data from an xml file, so the links were marked in it. I will paste that code, so you can base yours off of it, but unless you are doing exactly the same as we were then you'll have to modify it to get your links.

```
if (contentNode instanceof Element && contentNode.getNodeName().equals("section")) {
    String sectionTitle = ((Element) contentNode).getAttribute("title");
    article.headers.add(sectionTitle);
    NodeList sectionList = contentNode.getChildNodes();

    String text = "";
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>(), linkStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int k = 0; k < sectionList.getLength(); k++) {
        Node sectionNode = sectionList.item(k);

        if (sectionNode instanceof Element && sectionNode.getNodeName().equals("text")) {
            NodeList textNodes = sectionNode.getChildNodes();

            for (int l = 0; l < textNodes.getLength(); l++) {
                Node attributeNode = textNodes.item(l);

                text += attributeNode.getTextContent();
            }
        }

        if (sectionNode instanceof Element && sectionNode.getNodeName().equals("embedded_link")) {
            String linkDestination = ((Element) sectionNode).getAttribute("destination");
            String linkString = ((Element) sectionNode).getAttribute("string");

            linkStrings.add(linkString);
            links.add(linkDestination);
        }
    } // end k forloop

    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

    // Loop through all of the links.
    for (int m = 0; m < links.size(); m++) {
        final String linkString = linkStrings.get(m);
        final String link = links.get(m);

        final int start = text.indexOf(linkString);
        final int end = start + linkString.length();

        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(link));

                    context.startActivity(i);                                   
            }
        };

        if (start > -1) {
            try {
                spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("couldn't spannable text", linkString);
            }
        }
    } // end m forloop

    article.bodyContent.put(sectionTitle, spannableStringBuilder);
} // end if for section
```

Hopefully that all isn't too confusing. If you have more questions let me know.

Comment: Great. Ill try to modify the code. Im adding an edit to my question with an example string

Comment: i found a way to override the MovmentMethod to use my own so I could use an intent, but this resulted in the same thing(see main post edits)

Comment: You shouldn't have to make a custom movement method. If you have any special intent actions that need to take place you would do then in the code I provided you, in the declaration of the clickableSpan, where an intent is being created.

Comment: turns out it has nothing to do with the links... at some point I've broken something when the app closes.... so even switching apps does this now. or going home then reopening the app. Ill see if I can fix this

Comment: Was totally my fault... forgot a "!" on an exit condition so it was exiting when it enters the background when it shouldn't. should i just delete the question?

Comment: Possibly. If you leave it up someone might find something else in here helpful, but technically you found the error in your own question, which was caused by some other code not posted in the question. Honestly, I don't know one way or the other.